# Set select2 placeholder color with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

So this is how to set the color with Css:
`.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2selection__placeholder {color: #444;}`

But how can i change the color with Jquery using "this"?

`$(this).css('color', 'red')` Don't work.
`$(this)[0].css('color', 'red')` Don't work.
`$(this[0]).css('color', 'red')` Don't work.

**EDIT**
console.log( $this) )
`0:select#employment.form-control.select2.req_place`

Comment: Can you show us what you tried ? We can't tell why "this" is not working since we don't what "this" is referring to.

Comment: @ThEBiShOp Check edit..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `$(this)` shows that it is a `select` element. You need to find its sibling `.select2-container` which is what is shown on the UI. And within this sibling find `.select2-selection__placeholder` and change its color.

So use this code.

```
$(this).siblings('.select2-container').find('.select2-selection__placeholder').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Perfect!

Comment: @BjörnC enjoy your day :D

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this:

```
.select2-search__field::placeholder{
    color: #cecfd0;
}
.select2-search__field:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #cecfd0;
}
.select2-search__field::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #cecfd0;
}
```